# Mapping into multiple maps in parallel with Java 8 Streams

Tags: concurrency, java-8, hashmap, iterator, java-stream

I'm iterating over a CloseableIterator (looping over elements) and currently adding to a hashmap (just putting into a HashMap, dealing with conflicts as needed). My goal is to do this process in parallel, add to multiple hashmaps in chunks using parallelism to speed up the process. Then reduce to a single hashmap.

Not sure how to do the first step, using streams to map into multiple hashmaps in parallel. Appreciate help.

Comment: show your current implementation to better your description.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding concurrency with iterating over a collection, mapping to multiple hash maps and reducing to one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330711/adding-concurrency-with-iterating-over-a-collection-mapping-to-multiple-hash-ma)

Answer (score 0):

Parallel streams collected into [Collectors.toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) will already process the stream on multiple threads and then combine per-thread maps as a final step. Or in the case of `toConcurrentMap` multiple threads will process the stream and combine data into a thread-safe map.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) (as opposed to an [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) or a [`Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html)), it's probably not worth parallelizing. In [Effective Java](http://a.co/4fiiBiy), Josh Bloch states that:

> Even under the best of circumstances, parallelizing a pipeline is unlikely to increase its performance if the source is from [`Stream.iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-), or the intermediate operation `limit` is used.

An `Iterator` has only a `next` method, which (typically) must be called sequentially. Thus, any attempt to parallelize would be doing essentially what `Stream.iterate` does: sequentially starting the stream and then sending the data to other threads. There's a lot of overhead that comes with this transfer, and the cache is not on your side at all. There's a good chance that it wouldn't be worth it, except maybe if you have few elements to iterate over and you have a lot of work to do on each one. In this case, you may as well put them all into an `ArrayList` and parallelize from there.

---

It's a different story if you can get a reasonably parallelizable [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html). You can get these if you have a good `Iterable` or `Spliterator`. If you have a good `Spliterator`, you can get a `Stream` using the [`StreamSupport.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.Spliterator-boolean-) methods. Any `Iterable` has a [`spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#spliterator--) method. If you have a `Collection`, use the [`parallelStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#parallelStream--) method.

A `Map` in Java has key-value pairs, so I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "putting into a HashMap." For this answer, I'll assume that you mean that you're making a call to the `put` method where the key is one of the elements and the value `Boolean.TRUE`. If you update your question, I can give a more specific answer.

In this case, your code could look something like this:

```
public static <E> Map<E, Boolean> putInMap(Stream<E> elements) {
  return elements.parallel()
      .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(e -> e, e -> Boolean.TRUE, (a, b) -> Boolean.TRUE));
}
```

- `e -> e` is the key mapper, making it so that the keys are the elements.
- `e -> Boolean.TRUE` is the value mapper, making it so the set values are true.
- `(a, b) -> Boolean.TRUE` is the merge function, deciding how to merge two elements into one.

Comment: "If you only have an Iterator (not a Spliterator) then it's probably not worth parallelizing." Curious on the reasoning for this.